# HTML: Headers and Paragraphs

Tags: html

So, I have this code (escaped HTML):

```
<p><h3>1.</h3>No spamming.</p>
```

However, I want the content: `1.` to be on the same line as the content: `No spamming`. How can I arrange it to be on the same line?

Comment: What does your html look like? You can do anything with css, but that will depend on your html.

Comment: I wrote it out but that's what came out.

Comment: You need to give us a little more context. Please add the requested html

Comment: <p><h3>1.<h3>No Spamming</p>

Comment: There we go. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, I see. In the future, you need to put back ticks around your code to prevent it from actually being shown,

Comment: A heading inside a paragraph makes no sense semantically.

Comment: Or highlight it and click on the code sample {} button

Comment: Down votes are for "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"   Someone probably thought your question fell into one of those categories.

Comment: You should just use a span instead of your h3's

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<p><h3 style="display:inline">1.</h3>No spamming.</p>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Also, is there a way to do this in the css in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.inline-header {
display: inline
}
```

And then use this for your html:

```
<p><h3 class="inline-header">1.</h3>No spamming.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, can I label the h3 tag so that I can simply refer to that label in the css?

Comment: ideally, you add a class name to your h3. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated with class name.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buhv6doo/).

add this to css:

```
h3{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It actually creates a ordered list using `<ul>`. Every `<li>` (that is inside a `ol`) creates a new list item. I this is not what you really wanted but I know that you are trying to create a list. Here you go:

```
<ol>
<li>No spamming
</ol>
```